# Fusion Charts , JavaScript data click events C#

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-events, fusioncharts

I am creating fusion charts in .net, and Its working fine.

```
Chart MyFirstChart = new Chart(chartType, chartName, "100%", height.ToString(), "json", jsonData.ToString());
```

Data is collected from  data table from SQL server and converted to JSON string.

My data table has the following data :

- Date
- No of students
- Percentage
- Name of Department

I would like to add an event that if a data plot is clicked more details are shown by showing data from a different data table, which contains more details of that Department.

I added the event:

```
MyFirstChart.AddEvent("dataPlotClick" , "dataPlotClick");

// render chart
return MyFirstChart.Render();
```

And called this event in a Javascript

```
<script>
dataPlotClick =  function (eventObj, dataObj) {
console.log(eventObj);
var header = document.getElementById('header');
header.style.display = 'block';
var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
var attrsTable = document.getElementById('attrs-table');
var titleDiv, valueDiv;
for (var prop in dataObj) {
titleDiv = document.createElement('div');
titleDiv.className = 'title';
titleDiv.innerHTML = prop;
valueDiv = document.createElement('div');
valueDiv.className = 'value';
valueDiv.innerHTML = dataObj[prop];
tempDiv.appendChild(titleDiv);
tempDiv.appendChild(valueDiv);
}
attrsTable.innerHTML = '';
attrsTable.appendChild(tempDiv);};
</script>
```

The click on data plot works fine, but its gets the data of the current data table, and I would like to get the more detailed data table and show in a table view in the asp page.

Is there a way to do that?